# Parse-Server mongoerror authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I setup a local parse-server, it is working perfectly fine except when I enable authentication in MongoDB and change connection string to `mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/dbname`, the parse console throw the following error:

`unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames mongoerror authentication failed`

The client i.e. RoboMongo works fine too, with authentication. I even tried with a user that has both `userAdminAnyDatabase` and `dbAdminAnyDatabase` roles assigned to it just to ensure it is not a permission issue.

Update:
I was using MongoDB 3.2 so I tried to downgrade to MongoDB 3.0.12, still the same issue.

Update 2:
I even tried `root` role which has the highest privilege i.e. superuser but still no luck.

Comment: are you managed to connect the database from your command line interface?

Comment: Yes, both from command line and Robomongo

Comment: And you put the correct name and password ?  Because it looks like that it doesn't find the user

Answer (score 14):

Have you created a user for the specific database? If you try to connect using the mongo admin account you can experience this.

Create a user like this:

```
use dbName
db.createUser({ user: "userName", pwd: "password", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] })
```

and use that to connect to the database - then it should work

Comment: Creating a new user solved it for me - but I created it on mlab website in the users tab for the database.

Comment: Could you mark my suggestion as answer? If it helped you of course :)